# Javascript Palindrome function logic written correctly?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new to programming so please bear with me. I'm currently working on Functions Logic. I'm trying to write a function to see if the string passed is a palindrome or not (true or false).

Here is my code,

```
function palindrome(word){
  if(word === word.reverse())
    return true;
 } else {
    return false;
 };

 palindrome("ohho");
```

When I run this on the Google Inspect Element console. I get a syntax error that says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` regarding the  `} else {` I have a couple of questions,

1. Is the logic in my code correct?
2. Also, why am I getting a Syntax error?

Thanks!

Comment: You have an extra brace in the `} else {` line, you can remove both of them since you only have one line under each condition.

Comment: Strings don’t have a `reverse` method.

Comment: Your next error will be "undefined is not a function" :)

Comment: reverse is available on array not on string convert string to array and then use reverse

Answer (score 5):

It can be simplified as:

```js
function palindrome(word) {
  return word === Array.from(word).reverse().join('')
}

console.log(palindrome("ohho"))
console.log(palindrome("ohno"))
```

More efficient way :

```js
function palindrome(word) {
  var ln = word.length;
  for (var i = 0; i <= ln/2;) 
    if (word[i++] !== word[ln-i]) return false;
  return true
}

console.log(palindrome("ohho"))
console.log(palindrome("ohno"))
```

Try to handle uppercase, lowercase, spaces and punctuation yourself to check phrases like "Race car."

Comment: I didn't realize that `.reverse()` is a method that is meant to reverse the place of an array element. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: `Array.from(word).reverse().join('')` is more descriptive and does not fail on higher order unicode characters.

Comment: Or `Array.prototype.reverse.call(word).join('')` for <= es5

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that `reverse` is not a method under the String type. It will only work for Array checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

You can still hack around this by simply converting the string value to an array via the String [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method!

so `'ohho'.split('')` will result to the following `["o", "h", "h", "o"]` you can still reverse this array. I will prefer to leave the rest of the challenge to you ;)

---

Edited: @jeremy pointed out in the comment where split can fail with unicode character

> split("") is not appropriate for splitting a string into chunks. It fails on higher-order Unicode characters. Array.from(..) works properly

so I will recommend the use of `Array.from('ohho')` over `split`. one thing to note is that Array.from won't work with IE unless you have polyfill.

More info [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: `split("")` is not appropriate for splitting a string into chunks.  It fails on higher-order Unicode characters.    `Array.from(..)` works properly.

Comment: For <= es5 `Array.prototype.reverse.call(word).join('')` can be used.